# How to join socket.io room inside an async promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, socket.io

I am trying to make a socket join a room from inside a `.then()` but it's not working. I know everything else is correct in the code because after moving the `socket.join()` outside of the `.then()` and into a sync function it works. I try sending messages and no messages are sent when the join happens inside the promise. How can I make it work this way?

```
client.query('SELECT x FROM y WHERE f= $1;', ["example"])
.then((results) => {
    socket.join('test');// join room
    //more code that works properly..
})
```

Adding the message function:

```
socket.on('chat_message', function(data){
        io.to('test').emit('chat_message', data.msg);
    });
```

In more detail: (After Ben Aston suggested it)

```
socket.on('sock_on', function(data){
client.query('SELECT x FROM y WHERE xy = $1;', ['abcdef'])
                    .then(results => {
                            return client.query('SELECT * FROM x WHERE u= $1;', ['ghjkl'])
                            .then((results) => {
                            socket.join('test');// join room

                            var b= JSON.stringify(results.rows[0]);
                            socket.emit('loadB', b);
                            })  
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err.stack)
                    })
});

socket.on('chat_message', function(data){
        io.to('test').emit('chat_message', data.msg);
        //send msg to that room 
        //not being sent unless the join in the above
        //function is moved outside of the promises
    });
```

EDIT: I tried calling a function in the same line `socket.join()` is right now that basically lets sockets join rooms from there. It still does not work.

Comment: Have you verified that `client.query` is successful?

Comment: Yes it is, everything works perfectly except the socket.join().

Comment: You might need to supply some of the relevant surrounding code to help people answer.

Comment: @BenAston There really isnt much to add but i did anyway, hope it helps somehow. It should work shouldnt it? I dont get what the problem is.

Comment: you should totally `return` that second `client.query` inside the first `then`

Comment: @Onheiron Do you mean just use `return;` right before i close the `.then()` ?

Comment: just write `return` right before `client.query` everywhere :D

Comment: @Onheiron wait..before? Right above the second client.query? Just want to double check because it sounds weird to me. Also is this related to the question or just a useful tip?

Comment: like this `... results => { return client.query('SELECT * FROM x WHERE u= $1;', ['ghjkl'])...`. In general you should always `return` your promises because they chain: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining. So it's an useful tip (you might get a better error). While on that, how are you triggering that `socket.on('chat_message',...)`?

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that. The `socket.on()` is currently triggered when the client hits "send" to send a chat message with `socket.emit('chat_message', {msg});` . I really hope someone can help find what the issue is here i need it to work.

Comment: @Onheiron oops sorry forgot to tag you, don't know if you can see notifications for comments otherwise

Comment: and when is `sock_on` called instead?

Comment: @Onheiron It is called when the client clicks another button to log in. Basically the query checks his credentials and then lets him join a room. But he never joins it because it doesnt work :/ inside `.then()`